# Sqlite3: How to achieve performant read/write concurrency?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I'd like to be able to read from my DB (old un-updated data is fine) while also adding to the DB at a reasonable speed.

I have a large database that is being read by a script like this:

```
    con = sqlite3.connect(db_path)
    cur = con.cursor()

    cur.execute("SELECT move FROM history WHERE player = 'Joe'"
    for row in cur.fetchall():
        do_stuff(row[0])

    con.close()
```

While being generated by a separate script like this:

```
    con = sqlite3.connect(db_path)
    cur = con.cursor()
    
    with open(text_file) as raw_data:
        while (not_finished):
            entry_values = parse(raw_data)
            cur.executemany("INSERT INTO 'history' (player, move) VALUES (?,?)", entry_values)
    
    con.commit()
    con.close()
```

If I do it as above, the while loop runs ~150 times per second, but I get "sqlite3.OperationalError: database is locked" when I try to execute the SELECT.
If I move the commit() into the while loop, the SELECT succeeds within the timeout window, but the superfluous commits dramatically reduce performance.

I've tried and failed to wrap my head around isolation_level, WAL, reserved lock etc.  There must be a writing mode that doesn't block readers, but I don't know why I'm not in it by default or how to switch to it.?

Comment: If you need this kind of concurrency you might want to use a different database. This _might_ be possible, but it's not what SQLite is designed to do.

Comment: Normally you can have any number of active readers, or one active writer, but not both. With WAL mode, you can have any number of active readers, and a single active writer at the same time. If you need more than that, you need a different database.